# cannot find symbol type token in android studio?

Tags: android

```
private void loadFromAndToPlaceValues() {


        String str = loadJSONFromAsset();
        this.places = (List)new Gson().fromJson(str, newTypeToken<List<BusEntity>>().getType());
        if (this.places != null && this.places.size() > 0) {
            this.places_array = new String[this.places.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < this.places_array.length; i++) {
                this.places_array[i] = ((BusEntity) this.places.get(i)).getValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add log in question. also the proper description.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed `{}` braces. Change it like following.

```
this.places = (List)new Gson().fromJson(str, new TypeToken<List<BusEntity>>(){}.getType());
```

On a different note, question should be more constructive and descriptive. Posting plain code likely won't yield good answer most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you :

Option 1 - implement java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType yourself and pass it to Gson.

```
private static class ListParameterizedType implements ParameterizedType {

    private Type type;

    private ListParameterizedType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {type};
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return ArrayList.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }

    // implement equals method too! (as per javadoc)
}
```

Then simply:

```
Type type = new ListParameterizedType(clazz);
List<T> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

This will work too, at least with Gson 2.2.4.

```
Type type = com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(null, ArrayList.class, clazz);
```